# Using Selenium IDE to view webpage sources as in Google DevTools

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide, google-chrome

I am testing multiple webpages and I need to automatically check webpage sources as in Google DevTools. What I aim to achieve is to check, whether a source is present, so for example, if you look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/sources), I might (for example) want to check if source developer.google.com exists in this list.

This is what I Meant:
[image: Sources]

What I have is:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Command       |      Target      |      Value       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  execute script     |  return["U1",..] |  websiteArray    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  for each           |  websiteArray    |  iterator        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    echo             |  ${iterator}     |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    open             |  ${iterator}     |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  end                |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Is this possible in Selenium IDE? I would like to include this functionality in the for each loop, I haven't yet found any command that would seem to allow this in vanilla Selenium IDE, nor have I found any plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to check this ?

Comment: Even if you could do it in Selenium IDE, it sounds hacky to me. Why not find a tool that's geared towarsd what you need in the first place? I'm thinking something like Puppeteer.

Comment: You'll want to use a tool that has access to the dev tools, puppeteer for example. I'm not sure if if can access Sources, but worth a look. You'll need to know JavaScript to use puppeteer.

Comment: I do not know puppeteer unfortunately, I prefer gui where I can. I work with python, so I might as well look into Beautiful Soup and its functionality. @PDHide need to check if multiple websites have a third-party <script> tag inserted in <head></head> and are communicating with a certain analytics platform.

Comment: So what actually matters is whether events get sent to that platform? You're testing the *implementation*, not the *behaviour*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you could say that, I am testing just if a tag that is referencing a certain js on this very platform is in the header, which I can easily do just by looking at the sources and looking for the URL of that platform, I am not testing what data actually gets passed to that platform because this is done back on the platform by referencing the site id. However, I am successfully testing this using the method I described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I just used:

```javascript
var scripts = Array.prototype.slice
    .apply(document.querySelectorAll('script'))
    .filter(s => s.src)
    .map(s => s.src);

var stringScripts = scripts.toString();

var n = stringScripts.includes("url I am looking for");

console.log(n);
```

I have a simple for loop and I apply this to every page and then I just read the console, it seems to work consistently.